# How to sum documents' array size including parent item in sum with spring boot?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, aggregation

I have the following documents in a mongodb collection:

```
{
    "label": "first",
    "items": [
        {"foo":"bar"},
        {"foo":"foobar"},
    ]
},
{
    "label": "first",
    "items": [
        {"foo":"foobar"},
    ]
},
{
    "label": "second",
    "items": [
        {"foo":"ignored"},
    ]
}
```

I would like to get the sum of the array lengths **+ count of items** where `label` is `first`. So I would like to implement an aggregation method in spring with mongodb, to get a final number **5**.

3 (array lengths summed) + 2 (items found counted).

Answer (score 0):

```
Aggregation.newAggregation(
    Aggregation.match(
        where("label").`is`("first")
    ),

    Aggregation.group()
        .sum(
            ArithmeticOperators.Add.valueOf(1)
                .add(ArrayOperators.Size.lengthOfArray("items"))
        )
        .`as`("count")
)
```

This one works for me.